# Pausing, resuming and stopping threads in python

Tags: python, multithreading, redis, python-multithreading

I have a program that listens to messages from redis channel 'task_channel' and for each message it processes it in a new thread. I want to be able to control the pulling from redis to pause it, resume it, or end it at any point of time based on another redis channel 'control_channel'.
I already implemented this, but for some reason it doesn't pause! Here is my code:

```
import threading
import time
import redis
import os
import concurrent.futures

REDIS_HOST = os.getenv('NERVX_REDIS', '127.0.0.1')
REDIS_PORT = os.getenv('NERVX_REDIS_PORT', 6379)

r = redis.Redis(host=REDIS_HOST, port=REDIS_PORT)

class Scan:
    def __init__(self, redis_host='localhost', redis_port=6379, max_threads=3):
        self.redis_conn = r
        self.max_threads = max_threads
        self.is_processing = False
        self.executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=max_threads)
        self.control_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run_control_loop)
        self.control_thread.start()


    def process_message(self, message):
        print(f"Processing message: {message}")
        # Simulate some work
        time.sleep(2)
        print('done')

    def listen_to_redis_channel(self):
        while self.is_processing:
            message = self.redis_conn.blpop('tasks', timeout=5)
            if message:
                message = message[1].decode('utf-8')
                self.executor.submit(self.process_message, message)

    def pause_processing(self):
        self.is_processing = False

    def resume_processing(self):
        self.is_processing = True

    def stop_processing(self):
        self.is_processing = False
        # Wait for all threads to finish
        for thread in threading.enumerate():
            if thread != threading.current_thread():
                thread.join()

    def start(self):
        self.is_processing = True
        listener_thread = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)
        listener_thread.submit(self.listen_to_redis_channel)

    def run_control_loop(self):
        while True:
            command = self.redis_conn.blpop('control_channel', timeout=None)
            if command:
                command = command[1].decode('utf-8')
                if command == 'pause':
                    print('please paused!')
                    self.pause_processing()
                elif command == 'resume':
                    self.resume_processing()
                elif command == 'stop':
                    self.stop_processing()
                else:
                    print(f"Unknown command: {command}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    r.flushall()
    for i in range(100):
        r.rpush('tasks', f'test{i}')
    scan_instance = Scan()
    scan_instance.start()
    time.sleep(5)
    r.lpush('control_channel', 'pause')
    time.sleep(10)
```

For some reason this does not pause the pulling and it keeps pulling even after calling scan_instance.pause()